# CSS Selector - Select element by previous element text

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to select the category from several pages.

I have the following html:

```
<div class="comp-top col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 comp-stat">Rank</div>
        <div class="col-6 comp-value">5</div>
        <div class="col-6 comp-stat">Type</div>
        <div class="col-6 comp-value">Product</div>
        <div class="col-6 comp-stat">Category</div>
        <div class="col-6 comp-value">Store</div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

However, sometimes the html looks like that:

```
<div class="comp-top col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 comp-stat">Rank</div>
        <div class="col-6 comp-value">5</div>
        <div class="col-6 comp-stat">Category</div>
        <div class="col-6 comp-value">Store</div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

or like this:

```
<div class="comp-top col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 comp-stat">Type</div>
        <div class="col-6 comp-value">Product</div>
        <div class="col-6 comp-stat">Category</div>
        <div class="col-6 comp-value">Store</div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the position of the Category changes. I would like to create a css selector that grabs the text `Store` after the `Category` text.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: You want to grab the text or the element?

Comment: Also from your example, the Store element is the last one always so can't you use :last-child ?

Comment: I don't know what do you want to do... simply last child or add extra class to div Store element ??

Comment: Tried sibling ("+") selector? ".comp-stat + .comp-value { ... }".

Comment: You can't "grab" a text with CSS, but you can style it, so which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:last-child` selector for `.col-6` like this:

```
.col-6:last-child {
  color: red
}
```

Or,

This is not CSS but you can use JQuery `:contains` selector for your solution.

```
$( ".col-6:contains('Store')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
```